# Kendo Grid How to hide column in Angular scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I would like to ask, how to hide dynamically column in Kendo Grid in the Scope Angular JS function?

I tried to do by using this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/

**But if i'm trying to do same function in Angular scope function after ng-click:**

```
$scope.hideColumn = function () {
            console.log("Hidding");
            grid.hideColumn("user_role");
};
```

**I get error:**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.hideColumn
```

How can i do it properly (not only hidding, but locking, etc..) ?

Thans for any advice.

Comment: Your variable `grid` is probably undefined. Do you have it properly set via `<div kendo-grid="grid" ....`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a kendo grid name set by Kendo, you can access that from the $scope in your controller.

e.g.

```
    <div id="someId" data-kendo-grid="accessMeFromTheControllerID"
    k-auto-bind="false" 
    k-data-source-init={... removed for brevity...}
    k-columns="[
        { field: 'id', title: 'Id' },
        { field: 'columnToBeHidden', title: 'I should be hidden!' }
       ]"
    ></div>
```

You can access this from the controller and hide the column using:

```
$scope.accessMeFromTheControllerID.hideColumn('columnToBeHidden');
```

If you want to use JQuery (not angular-ish but can be good to know)

```
$("#accessMeFromTheControllerID").data("kendoGrid").hideColumn('customerName');
```